# how to Deserialize Json response from WCF Restful Service?

Tags: json, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, rest

I want to deserialize a Json response into my class object. I have created a WCF Restful Service, and from client using proxy object I'm calling a service method which return me a json. Now I want to convert that json into my class object.
My service is as follow:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "GetProject/{projectID}")]
    tblProject GetProject(String projectID);
```

Implementations:

```
public tblProject GetProject(String projectID)
        {
            tblProject pro = new tblProject();
            pro = DAL.ProjectDAL.GetProject(Convert.ToInt32(projectID));
            return pro;
        }
```

and from controller in MVC I'm making request as:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/RestServiceLibrary.RESTService/REST_ProjectService/getproject/2");
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                string txtResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
return view();
    }
```

and when I run I'm getting response as:

[image]

and when I call through a proxy method I got exception:

[image]

but my endpoints are there in config as,

[image]

Comment: You are not using WCF proxy client, instead you are making you are making http request call. Why don't you use WCF proxy it should handle deserialization for you?

Comment: @Enes I updated my question please review it.

Comment: REST services don't use proxies - that's a feature of SOAP web services.

Comment: @Tim so I can only use WebRequest?

Comment: @NomiAli - As I understand it for a RESTful service, yes, or some other HTTP-oriented approach (like `HttpClient`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [javascriptserializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string s = "YouJsonText";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.Deserialize(s);
//or
YouCustomClass res = serializer.Deserialize<YouCustomClass>(sb.ToString());
```

Also, you can use CustomJsonConverter like this:

```
public class YouCustomClassConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
  public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type,                      JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

   //and first you need register type, which you want Deserialize
   public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
   {
      get { return new[] { typeof(YouCustomClass ) }; }
   }

}

//and then example of using JavaScriptSerializer with custom converter
var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
ser.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new YouCustomClassConverter() });
try
{
     YouCustomClass obj = ser.Deserialize(jsonString);
}
```

Note: you need use `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`

Answer (score 1):

```
class GetProjectResultWrapper
    {
        public GetProjectResult GetProjectResult{ get; set; }
    }
    class GetProjectResult 
    {
        public string id {get;set;}
        .....
        ......
    }
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    GetProjectResultWrapper response = ser.Deserialize<GetProjectResultWrapper>(sb.ToString());
response .GetProjectResult;
```

Comment: I'm getting null in all properties of GETProjectResultClass, as it's not deserialize! @sakir

Comment: did u create GetProjectResultClass  properlly?

Comment: I'm actually using DataContract class object on client. @sakir I do not create a same class in model, using the service datacontract class.